# Create a Material Ui checkbox with textfiled

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, textfield

How to create a Material ui checkbox which when checked will disable Textfield and fixed the alignment?

Link to sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-mfnqk?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should utilize the [List component provided by Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/). Give it the alignItems="center" prop to fix the alignment. Then, the Material UI Checkboxes component accepts a boolean for the disabled prop so you should have that set to the value of 'checked' in your state hooks. That way, when 'checked' is updated, the disabled prop updates as well. I also added a fullWidth prop to the textField to make it less cluttered. [A live demo can be found here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-25uft?file=/demo.tsx), but here's how I worked it out:

```
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function Checkboxes() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <List>
        <ListItem alignItems="center">
          <Checkbox
            checked={checked}
            onChange={handleChange}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
          />
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            disabled={checked}
            label="disable when checkbox checked"
          />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem alignItems="center">
          <Typography variant="subtitle1" style={{ marginRight: "3px" }}>
            Hello
          </Typography>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            disabled={!checked}
            label="enable when checkbox checked"
          />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid container alignContent="center" alignItems="center" direction="row" xs={12}>
    <Grid item xs="auto">
        <Checkbox />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs>
        <TextField fullWidth label="I am a Textbox" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Checkbox, FormControl, FormControlLabel, Grid, InputAdornment, InputLabel, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { CheckBoxChecked, CheckBoxUnChecked } from "@components/Icons";

interface TextFieldCheckBoxProps {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  label?: string;
  value: string;
  options: string[];
  onChange?: (option: string) => void;
  onBlur?: (event) => void;
}

const TextFieldCheckBox: React.FC<TextFieldCheckBoxProps> = ({options,...props}) => {
  
  const [ ,setSelectedOption] = useState<string>(options[0]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (option: string) => {
    setSelectedOption(option);
    props.onChange && props.onChange(option);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl
      id={props.id} 
      sx={{
        display: "inline-flex",
        flexDirection: "initial",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifycontent: "center",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        border: "0px solid blue"
      }}
    >
      
{/****** LABEL *****/}
      <Grid container gap={1.5} sx={{border:"0px solid black", }}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sx={{border:"0px solid blue"}}>
            <InputLabel  
              sx={{
                  display: "flex",
                  margin: "0px",
                  transform: "translate(0px, -6px) scale(0.75)",
                }}
              >
              <Typography 
                sx={{
                    textAlign: "left",
                    color: "#3E3D3D",
                    fontFamily: "montserrat",
                    fontWeight: 700,
                    fontSize: "1.8rem",
                  }}
                >
                {props.label}
              </Typography>
          </InputLabel>
        </Grid>

{/*** BODY ***/}
        <Grid item xs={12} 
          sx={{    
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "flex-start",
            gap: "2rem",
          }}
        >
          {options.map((option, index) => (
            <FormControlLabel  
              key={index}
              control={
                <TextField
                  id={`meu-textfield-custom-${index}`}
                  variant="standard"
                  InputProps = {{  
                    startAdornment: 
                      <InputAdornment position="start" id="meu-InputAdornment-custom"
                        sx={{
                          marginTop: "0px !important",
                          "& .MuiInput-root":{
                            border:"1px solid red",
                            marginTop: "0px !important",
                          }
                        }}
                        >
                        <Checkbox
                          // checked={selectedOption === option}
                          onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(option)}
                          inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
                          icon={<CheckBoxUnChecked style={{fontSize: "1.5rem"}}  />}
                          checkedIcon={<CheckBoxChecked style={{fontSize: "1.5rem"}} />}
                          sx={{
                            padding: "0px",
                            "&.Mui-checked": {
                              color: "#D91F05 !important",
                            }
                          }}
                        />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  }}
                  sx={{
                    border: '0px solid red',
                    display: 'flex',
                    width: 'auto',
                    "& label": {
                      // Controle de estilo antes de digitar
                      color: "#3E3D3D",
                      fontFamily: "montserrat",
                      fontWeight: 700,
                      fontSize: "1.8rem",
                      borderRadius: "1rem",
                      opacity: "1",
                      top: "-12px",
                      minWidth: "fit-content",
                    },
                    '& .MuiInputBase-root:before': {
                      border: 'none !important',
                    },        
                    '& .MuiInputBase-root:hover:not(.Mui-disabled, .Mui-error):before': {
                      border: "0px solid white !important",
                    },
                    '& input': {
                      display: 'none !important',
                    },
                    '& .MuiInputBase-adornedStart': {
                      margin: '0px !important',
                    },
                  }}
                >
                </TextField>  
              }
              label={option}
              sx={{
                "& .MuiFormControlLabel-label": {
                  fontFamily: "montserrat",
                  fontWeight: 500,
                  color: "#3E3D3D",
                },
                width: "fit-content",
                margin: "0px",
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default TextFieldCheckBox;
```